# ssh key install

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh

I wrote script to install public key of my system to remote host.
I had tested the script it is working fine for me.
script take data like IP password and ssh port form CVS file.
I do not want to use import os.
only use CSV and paramiko imports.
My aim is to copy public key to my remote host.

```
import csv
import os

from paramiko import SSHClient, AuthenticationException, AutoAddPolicy

username = "root"
key = open(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')).read()

with open("hostinfo.csv") as h:
    host = csv.reader(h, delimiter=",")
    for i in host:
        # csv file field ip,pass,port
        HostIP, HostPass, HostPort = i[0], i[1], i[2]
        try:
            client = SSHClient()
            client.load_system_host_keys()  
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy)  
            client.connect(HostIP, HostPort, username, HostPass)
            print("Running commands on {0} port {1}".format(HostIP, HostPort))
            client.exec_command('mkdir -p ~/.ssh/')
            client.exec_command('echo "%s" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' % key)
            client.exec_command('chmod 644 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys')
            client.exec_command('chmod 700 ~/.ssh/')
            print("Key is installed in {0}".format(HostIP))
        except AuthenticationException:
            raise AuthenticationException('Authentication failed: did you remember to create an SSH key?')
        finally:
            client.close()
            print("connection is closed")
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use [ssh-copy-id](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id)? 

It would copy over the public key to the server you desire.

Comment: If I want to install public key in 2000 servers then can I use ssh-copy-id and type password or export data to CSV then use script and Wait for output

Comment: What data are you collecting? I had assumed all you wanted to do was copy the public key to '2000' servers. Is there specific information you need from each time you copy the key over?

Comment: 2000 server is just for example ; my script is working but can you improve it. I not want os module to use in this script. Only CSV and paramiko I want.@zchpyvr

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you don't need a Python script, there is already a well-written command-line utility for this exact scenario: ssh-copy-id. I recommend looking it up.

Comment: Sir you are not understand my point.

Comment: I know command but I have CSV dump data and all servers not have same sab port and this script is helpful for me to copy my keys to server by not typing any password.@Zchpyvr

Comment: @Zchpyvr try to copy you ssh key to 200 server with ssh-copy-id then answer me what you feel to doing this for all day

Comment: Ok fine. Even if you have settled that is the best approach-- I'm confused why you don't want to import os when os is a core Python library-- it's guaranteed to be there every time you run this script. Can you explain your reasoning behind that requirement?

Comment: @Zchpyvr it is my personal point of view I don't like to import os.

Comment: Then use the full absolute path for the key file? Something like `/home/my-user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`? That way you don't need to import os.